# How to send int value from form to usercontrol

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm Working on a game that uses multiple layouts. To make those layouts, I use user controls by bringing them forward and sending them behind. Now I'm in a phase where I have to send all gathered data (hardness, what type etc) to User control where all rest of the work is done. I'm stuck with sending int values to my user control that does all the work. I thought about sending them with eventhandler, but EventHandler didn't seem to recognize my int values either

In short, I want to pass Int values that I have in a form, to User control

```
        public void liitmine1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*event*/
        uCraskus1.BringToFront();
        int What = 1;

    }
    public void kumme(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        uCmehanism1.BringToFront();
        int Between = 1;
    }
    public event EventHandler KummeClick; /*Sends info to mechanism*/
    private void KummeNupp(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(What == 1) /*The name'what' does not exist in current context error*/
        if (this.KummeClick != null)
            this.KummeClick(this, e);
    }
```

`if (this.KummeClick != null)` is just to test, don't mind if anything is wrong with that

Comment: Expose an `int` property (public property) in your `UserControl` and set it from your `form` code behind.

Comment: In your example you defined `What` as a local variable. Of course it is not visible when you do not define it a a class membeber. But this type of using a variable is not the bes idea.

Comment: You can also add a buffer class on the side, full of static properties or such, just to get the needed data easily. It's not high quality code, but it's not bad either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your own EventArgs type, like this:

```
public class KummeClickEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    }
```

And then use it (assumption that kumme method is one of the subscribers):

```
public void kumme(object sender, KummeClickEventArgs e)
    {
        //here is your logic like:
        //int test = e.MyProperty;

        uCmehanism1.BringToFront();
        int Between = 1;
    }
    public event EventHandler<KummeClickEventArgs> KummeClick; /*Sends info to mechanism*/
    private void KummeNupp(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(What == 1) /*The name'what' does not exist in current context error*/
        if (this.KummeClick != null)
        {
            var eventArgs = new KummeClickEventArgs
            {
                MyProperty = 3
            };
            this.KummeClick(this, eventArgs);
        }
    }
```